# ssh executing commands remotely, how PATH is determined?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script that uses ssh to execute commands remotely.
I spotted however quite considerable difference in behaviour depending whether I launch commands in the background or not:

```
ssh host cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

vs.

```
ssh host "cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3" &
```

In the second case, some commands are not executed correctly because they don't appear on $PATH. It seems the environment is different in those two situations (when passing env as command I noticed quite considerable differences).

How to explain that ?

I know I could override PATH variable but is there a way to do it more in a elegant way to have the second example behave like first with "&" feature ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first command you are probably executing cmd2 and cmd3 on the local host, not the remote one. The `&&` words are interpreted by the local shell and not passed as arguments to ssh.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is set while compiling `sshd`:

```
[~]> grep PATH /etc/sshd_config         
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Always use absolute paths while executing a remote command.